# How do I locate a batch file

Tags: batch-file, location

So I am writing a little program in batch, and I am hoping it will be able to run it on other's computers. My `cd` is to `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\,\thing`, but that is not where other people may store it. How can I locate where it is and do a `cd` to it? Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and give more informations ! did you mean the location of your current batch ? or post the hole code !

Comment: Sorry, I meant: how do I get to where the batch file is stored, which is in `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\,\thing on my computer. Some other files are stored here, and I need them too. I want this code to be able to run on other people's computers too, and I don't know where they will store it. So how do I locate the file in their computer?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to get the path of the current batch where it is executed ?

Comment: Yes. You took the words rite out of my mouth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%cd%`  is available either to a batch file or at the command prompt and expands to the drive letter and path of the current directory (which can change e.g. by using the CD command)

`%~dp0` is only available within a batch file and expands to the drive letter and path in which that batch file is located (which cannot change). It is obtained from `%0` which is the batch file's name.

```
@echo off
echo %appdata%
CD %appdata%
pause
echo %CD%
pause
Dir 
pause
echo "%~dp0%"
pause
CD "%~dp0%"
Dir 
cls
echo this is %%cd%%  %cd%
echo this is %%~dp0 %~dp0
pause
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: @Cubby So, if you found that script is helpful, you can upvote it and mark it as "accepted" ==> [Take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Programs and documents can be added to the registry so typing their name without their path in the Start - Run dialog box or shortcut enables Windows to find them.

This is a generic reg file. Copy the lines below to a new Text Document and save it as anyname.reg. Edit it with your programs or documents.

In paths use `\\` to seperate folder names in key paths as regedit uses a single \ to seperate it's key names. All reg files start with REGEDIT4. A semicolon turns a line into a comment. The @ symbol means to assign the value to the key rather than a named value.

The file doesn't have to exist. This can be used to set Word.exe to open Winword.exe.

This sample add IE.Txt (from IE5) to the registry so typing IE.Txt will open it. I think the file is called IE4.txt in IE4.

```
REGEDIT4
;The bolded name below is the name of the document or program, <filename>.<file extension> 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IE.txt]

;The @ means the path to the file is assigned to the default value for the key.
;The whole path in enclosed in a quotation mark ".

@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IE.txt\""

;Optional Parameters. The semicolon means don't process the line. Remove it if you want to put it in the registry

;Informs the shell that the program accepts URLs.

;"useURL"="1"

;Sets the path that a program will use as its' default directory. This is commented out.

;"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office\\"
```

`reg` command can read or write to the registry in batch. Register it as if it's an exe file not a batch file.

Comment: wait, so instead of writing `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\,\thing` I could write `regedit14`?